# htaccess problem on laravel, can't load css js and other routes

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-7, php-7.3

I have some problem with .htaccess on Laravel 7.16.1,

1. i have laravel installed on root folder something like this : /var/www/user/
2. i have renamed server.php on root folder to index.php

the problem is, laravel is index route is working fine but **cannot access other route** (eg. login, register, and my routes) also **can't load assets** (css,js) so the web is bare bone because it can't load css and js. **but it can load css and js on public folder**, like mydomain.com/public/asset.js. etc

**i have tried several solution on stack overflow before** by changing the .htaccess on root folder and public path, but none of them working !

here is my default htaccess on root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

what is the correct .htaccess to solve this problem ? thank you.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/549517/what-does-apaches-require-all-granted-really-do

Comment: i don't have sudo access to the server, so i can't change the apache config @TahaPaksu

Comment: Do you know your Apache version?